# running script on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone on SO helped me write this script for a select box which will show hidden rows based on the selected choice in the dropdown

```
function showNext(opt)  {
    takeAway()
    var optMap={
        "Picked Up":"#pickedup",
        "Bus to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
        "Walk to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
    }
    $(optMap[opt]).css("display","") ;
}

function takeAway(){
    $("#pickedup,#altad2,#altad1").css("display", "none");
}
```

I need something that will work for this to run onload as well so if something is already selected the rows show

Here is the select that would be affected by the script

```
<tr class="~[evenoddrow]"> 
            <td class="bold">In the event of early dismissal I would like my child to:</td><td id="Emergclose_Action">~([01]Emergclose_Action)</td><td class="gwCen"></td>
            <td><select name="eReg|Emergclose_Action" id="eReg|Emergclose_Action" onChange="showNext(value);">
                    <option></option><option value="Walk home as normal">Walk home as normal</option><option value="Ride the bus as normal">Ride the bus as normal</option>
<option value="Picked Up">Be picked up immediately after dismissal</option><option value="Bus to alternate">Ride the bus to an alternate address</option><option value="Walk to alternate">Walk to an alternate address</option>
                </select>           
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I tried the following and it did not work..

```
function showNext(opt)  {
        takeAway()

      var optMap={
             "Picked Up":"#pickedup",
             "Bus to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
             "Walk to alternate":"#altad2,#altad1",
              }
           $(optMap[opt]).css("display","") ;       

}
function takeAway(){
    $("#pickedup,#altad2,#altad1").css("display", "none");
 }
$(function(){
   $('#eReg|Emergclose_Action').trigger('onchange');
});
```

Comment: It seems to me there are some missing pieces. Is the `showNext` method attached to the `onchange` event of `#eReg|Emergclose_Action`?

Comment: I also tried it with your example UpHelix and that did not work either

Comment: Your question is confusing. Which exact method do you want ran onload and is that method attached to a DOM element?

Comment: Not sure how to answer your question (im rather green) I would like the onChange="showNext(value); to be triggered onload.. let me edit out the stuff above that don't apply to this particular scenario maybe that's causing confusion

Comment: I updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `onChange="showNext(value);"` from your select element and change the id. Having a pipe `|` in a selector isn't good practice and [requires a work-a-round](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-en/3CVzhy5N1vk)... easier without it. Replace it with an underscore `_` instead.

So your html for the select is:

```
<select name="eReg|Emergclose_Action" id="eReg_Emergclose_Action">
```

Then do the javascript this way:

```
$(function(){

   //anything in here will run after the page loads

   //assign showNext to the change event
   $('#eReg_Emergclose_Action').change(function(){
      showNext($(this).val());
   }).change();//manually trigger the change event after its attached

});
```

Comment: kind of I think.. I edited the original post to include the select. maybe that will help

Answer (score 0):

The script that you have to run on page load if someone had already selected yes previously,  can be optimized like below using Jquery

$('#eReg|Emergclose_Action').trigger('onchange');

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) not the question i was asking but helpful nonetheless :)

Comment: or maybe it was i misread still could not get it to work however:)